# Explanation and formula for Modified Z-score?

Tags: median, z-score, robust-standard-error

I'm struggling understanding and finding a reference for Modified (robust) z-score.
I found a [reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=terms-modified-z-score) that says I have to adjust by 1.25 or 1.48 depending on the value of the median absolute deviation.

I've found resources (e.g, [here](http://www.estepsoftware.com/papers/madrsquare.pdf) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.0/topics/mad)) that rely on either 1.25 or 1.48 without saying how they got that adjustment.

Can someone please explain the formula for robust z-scores?

Comment: That first link no longer works — can you post an updated link or another reference?

Comment: I have fixed the first link